# How does .NET applications probing for their configuration files?

Tags: .net, configuration

I know there's some kind of assembly probing process. Is there a similar process for looking for config files? If there is, what exact process is it? How could I customize it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you mean asp.net web configs? Because windows apps don't probe that file (unless you wish it).

Comment: What kind of customisation are you looking forward for?

Comment: @silky:I mean both WinForm app and ASP.NET app.

Comment: @Kangkan: I want different assembly DLLs of my application to use different config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class libraries does not have their own config files but rather use the one of the application so you can't get exactly what you want. However, there might be ways to mimic this in certain ways depending on exactly what you need.

Here's a blog post that discusses a possible solution to this:
http://moebiusit.com/blog/2010/07/13/changing-dll-settings-without-re-compiling/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you wish to initiate or load different class/object (in different DLLs) with a different set of configuration. So the pattern that supports such needs is the Dependency Injector. You can look into some DI framework for this. The standard config loading does not provide such functionality.